# "wilinq" LINQ to TFS: I cannot resolve all dependencies

Tags: c#, linq, tfs, visual-studio-2013

I'm attempting to make use of a library called [Wilinq](https://wilinq.codeplex.com/), which is supposed to give the ability to perform LINQ queries against TFS work items easily. There is a demo program available [here](https://github.com/miiitch/Wilinq-demo), but I cannot get it to build and run using Visual Studio 2013.

It appears that the library is relatively up to date, but I noticed that the references that the demo program contains to *not* match the available DLLs I have from Microsoft.

Also, the sample code tries to refer to a member function called `WorkItemSet()` in a `TfsTeamProjectCollection` object, but that method doesn't exist.

I suspect I have a different version of the TFS DLLs compared to the author of this Wilinq library, but I'm not sure. Does anyone know what's going on here?

*Another question I wouldn't mind hearing your answers about is whether there is another recommended LINQ-to-TFS library out there, but that's off-topic for StackOverflow... I won't complain, though!*

Here are the dependencies from the demo program:

```
* Microsoft.TeamFoundation
  Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client
* Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.Library
  Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client
  Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Common
```

The references marked with an asterisk are the ones I don't have.

Here are the DLLs that are in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0`

```
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities.dll
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.dll
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Common.dll
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.dll
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Deployment.Workflow.dll
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Diff.dll
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Discussion.Client.dll
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.dll
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Common.dll
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.dll
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Common.dll
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Common.Integration.dll
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.DataStoreLoader.dll
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.dll
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.QueryLanguage.dll
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Common.dll
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Proxy.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

Install TFS (Preferably the same version that you want to target). There are some differences between TFS versions. I had to change (and in some cases completely gut and rewrite) code targeting TFS2010 when we upgraded to TFS2012.  Not all the libraries are installed on a client machine.

After TFS is installed, you will find the libraries needed in :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies
```

or

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies
```

or

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies
```

Depending on the TFS version you are targeting. (Of course if you already have TFS installed on a server, just copy the files from there).

You can then either reference these directly or copy them.  Remember to set copy local to true as this is NOT part of .NET and is normally not installed in GAC.